Python request to second endpoint fails after using client certificate to first endpoint
I am using Python's requests package to make API calls. I have two different API endpoints I am making calls against. The first is to "https://api.example.com" and the second is to "https://work.myserver.com". The first API endpoint requires the use of a client certificate while the second does not. I find that once I make the call to the endpoint that requires the client certificate subsequent calls to the other endpoint fail with the error "SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_UNKNOWN_CA] tlsv1 alert unknown ca".
My guess is that after I have made a call using a client certificate all the calls that come after no matter to which endpoint are made using the client certificate.
How do I tell requests to not use the client certificate for all the other endpoints, and only to use it for the endpoint that requires it?
My code looks like this:
import requests

# Set up the key-pair paths
cert_path = "/etc/application/client.crt"
key_path  = "/etc/application/client.key"
keypair_paths = (cert_path, key_path)

response1 = requests.get(
    "https://api.example.com",
    cert=keypair_paths,
)

response2 = request.get("https://work.myserver.com") # This endpoint does NOT use client certificates

I am using version 2.32.3 of the requests package.
UPDATE At Andrej Kesely's suggestion I tried putting the requests in a requests.Session "with"-context, but that did not fix it. I have worked around the issue for now by using the urllib library for the call that requires Basic auth. However, the original problem remains unresolved.

Can you try to use session? with requests.session() as s: s.cert = ...; s.get(...);

I tried this but still not working.

I am wondering if my problem is the same as this one: https://github.com/psf/requests/pull/6731
